# Extract date from varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql-10

i have a table with those information:

```
July 16th 2018, 11:16:35.408    July 16th 2018, 11:16:35.408    appointmentCard flip    event       5afa7e01-6045-4ff5-b2d7-1933cd16ebca
July 16th 2018, 11:16:18.649    July 16th 2018, 11:16:18.649    5afa7e01-6045-4ff5-b2d7-1933cd16ebca
```

What i need is to extract date and hour in two different columns.
I've tried:

```
select
    to_char(mlk.time, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as Date,
    to_char(mlk.time, 'HH24:MI') as Hours
from main_source_multichannel mlk 
    inner join main_source_orders ord on mlk.trackingid = ord.trackingid
```

Without success, Postgresql is giving me this error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function to_char(character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 10
  ERROR: function to_char(character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 10
  ERROR: function to_char(character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 10
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: "What i'm doing wrong?" Using `varchar` as data type for timestamps in your table. Use the appropriate type `timestamp` instead.

Comment: What table are you describing above? I would recommend adding a little more time to the question you have asked.

Comment: The source is giving me the column as you read it if i import the column as timestamp Postgresql gives me: SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "July 16th 2018, 11:16:35.408"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting of your dates makes it slightly more complicated than it needs to be. I'd use a subquery to parse this into a timestamp, then it becomes a simple matter of extracting the date and time. Here is an example of how to do this: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/13f6cf/12)

In your case, something like:

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT to_timestamp(mlk.time, 'MonBDDBBBYYYYBBHH:MI:SS:MS') AS dateTime
  FROM main_source_multichannel mlk 
  INNER JOIN main_source_orders ord on mlk.trackingid = ord.trackingid
)
SELECT dateTime::date AS theDate, dateTime::time AS theTime
FROM dates
```

As the other answer(s) suggest, storing your data as a proper timestamp would eliminate the need for the subquery, and you'd just need a simple SELECT.

Comment: That's great thenks! I knew that it was slightly more complicated than usual!.

Answer (score 0):

I might try something like the following in your `SELECT`.

```
SELECT
to_char((mlk.time)::TIMESTAMP) , 'yyyy-mm-dd')    AS date
,to_char((mlk.time)::TIMESTAMP), 'HH24:MI')       AS hours
```

If you can, I would also attempt to store the data as a `TIMESTAMP`
If you cannot cast the column to a `::TIMESTAMP`, then you might need to fix those records.